# Is there a damage phase in the final round of Steampunk Rally?

Tags: steampunk-rally

In Steampunk Rally - a player crossing the finish line triggers one more final round, and then the winner is determined by who finishes the furtherest along the track.

The question I have is - during this final round - is there still a damage phase - in which an invention may explode and be taken back to last place?

Comment: What makes you think there isn't?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. There's nothing that indicates it should be skipped on the last round. Effectively, you can't just walk across the finish line; you need to have a machine to win.